# Is it okay to run EGL commands on Dispatchers.Default in android?

Tags: android, opengl-es, thread-safety, kotlin-coroutines, dispatcher

As I understand, the EGL14.makeCurrent() function maps the thread to the EGLContext we created. And every EGL operations we execute will be executed on the EGLContext tied to the thread.

Is it safe to perform EGL operations wrapped with Dispatchers.Default? According to docs,
""Dispatchers.Default is backed by a shared pool of threads on JVM. By default, the maximum number of threads used by this dispatcher is equal to the number of CPU cores, but is at least two.""

So will my EGL operations switch thread in Dispatchers.Default and the EGLContext be unavailable for the thread I am in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not safe to call EGL function from the same thread which was linked to a EGL context.

You can create a dedicated thread to handle EGL calls and construct Dispatcher for them.

Something like this:

```
val dispatcher = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().asCoroutineDispatcher()

suspend fun init() {
    withContext(dispatcher) {
        EGL14.makeCurrent() 
    }
}

suspend fun render() {
    withContext(dispatcher) {
        EGLFun()
    }
}
```

Comment: So is it ok to do something like this. I want to edit video using mediacodecs and am using egl to edit my frames.. I want to be able to edit multiple videos simultaneously. Thus create a serviceScope in my service.. serviceScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + SupervisorJob()). Doesn't matter which dispatcher as I would be switching to single threaded dispatcher for each edit. So for ever edit request:: serviceScope.launch{ with(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().asCoroutineDispatcher()){ startEditing() }.... To be continued..

Comment: Then.. on logout.. I would stop the service.. and in my onDestroy I would call serviceScope.cancel() to stop all my jobs.. P.S. I am checking ensureActive() in my startEditing() for each frame..